# Google ad was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event

Tags: javascript, error-handling, adsense

When I go to my website no ads are displaying even though I set one at the bottom of the page. It returns error - *The resource https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20181107/r20180604/show_ads_impl.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.* Yes, adblocker is disabled Here's my code for ad:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block; text-align:center;"
     data-ad-layout="in-article"
     data-ad-format="fluid"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9121789382833091"
     data-ad-slot="8487804504"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: It is a piece of html and “it was preloaded using link” is a css error

Comment: You should only use tags if you think experts on that technology are able to determine the cause. Your question is clearly JavaScript and, in fact, it's strictly adsense related. Normally you shouldn't have given me the right to close it as duplicate. Which doesn't mean you didn't have to check if it was asked before, though.

Comment: That’s so dumb, it isn’t a duplicate, if you don’t understand the question simply skip it

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I'm encountering the same problem, and indeed this has nothing in common with the so called duplicate answer you're pointing to. Can you please "unblock" this question?

Comment: @fbparis flag it as in need of moderator attention

Comment: If you checked everything on [this list](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1208336?visit_id=636780646550952418-3341898129&rd=1) and it still doesn't work, you should ask adsense for support.

Comment: Has anybody found a solution for this problem? I get the warning too and sometimes the same page displays the ad and sometime not...

Comment: @resizemyimg.com i did, the google simply didn’t allow my website

Comment: @Jake how did you check this not allowing thing?

Comment: @resizemyimg.com in my adsense account

Comment: @Jake can you be more specific? I want to see if i am banned or something, because only on my homepage the is ad is not showing...

Comment: @resizemyimg.com I don’t really remember how but I know your site will probably get banned if you have other ads there, add more than 3 ad of google or your website is a subdomain

Comment: Encountering this issue now, no other signs that this has been resolved.

Comment: Same issue as well. Desperately need a solution

Answer (score 5):

I suspect this is not the reason why ads doesn't show because after a few hours without updating the source code of the page the ads finally display, but the warning is still here in the javascript console.

I've noticed that every time I'm updating the source code, the ads disappear again for a few hours so I guess Google doesn't really "trust" me and ads are automatically suspended till a bot or something comes back to check that everything is OK.

Comment: Same here, maybe submitting the URL to Google Webmaster Tools can help solve the issue quicker.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Cloudflare? I fixed this by disabling rocket loader on the adsense script.

```
data-cfasync="false"
```

I have read multiple times that rocket loader has no negative effect on Adsense, now I am not so convinced.

Comment: Actually I figured out this happened because of I was trying to use subdomain for ad registration or something